При подтверждении номера через python requests не приходит смс
Я решил сделать авторег яндекс почт с подтверждением по смс. Использую python requests. За основу взял чужой репозиторий с github'а, всё шло хорошо пока я не попытался подтвердить номер. Запрос успешно обрабатывался, однако смс на номер не приходило. Долго игрался с headers но результатов это не принесло.
Код:
import requests
import bs4

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Origin': 'https://passport.yandex.ru',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://passport.yandex.ru/',
}
session = requests.session()
session.headers = headers
r = session.get('https://passport.yandex.ru/registration/')
bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
tmp = str(bs.find('script', {'id': "storeScript"}))
csrf_track = tmp.split('"csrf":"')[1].split('"')[0]
track_id = r.text.split('"registerTrackId":"')[1].split('"')[0]
phone = '79306807397'
data = {
    'track_id': track_id,
    'csrf_token': csrf_track,
    'number': '+7 ' + phone[1:],
    'isCodeWithFormat': True,
    'confirm_method': 'by_sms',
}
r = session.post(
    'https://passport.yandex.ru/registration-validations/phone-confirm-code-submit', headers=headers,
    data=data).text
print(r)

Вот пример ответа от phone-confirm-code-submit
{"status": "ok", "track_id": "d2de23f63baa51fb9e106fb1c75d1ec799", "deny_resend_until": 1729166753,
     "code_length": 6, "protocol": None,
     "number": {"masked_original": "+7 930*****97", "masked_international": "+7 930 ***-**-97",
                "masked_e164": "+7930*****97", "original": "+7 9306807397", "international": "+7 930 680-73-97",
                "e164": "+79306807397"}, "id": "d2de23f63baa51fb9e106fb1c75d1ec799", "now": "1729166693711"}

Проверял на номерах с сервисов(smshub,smshelper), физ сим, e-sim. После некоторых экспериментов я понял, что ошибка где-то в коде. Прошу, помогите!
P.S. 79306807397 - это случайный номер

Заметил несоответствие с рабочим ответом. В моём ответе на запрос "protocol": None, хотя должно быть "protocol": "sms". Однако причину такого ответа от сервера я не нашёл

Попробовал библиотеку tls_client вместо requests и задал идентификатор как 'chrome_112'. После этого как по волшебству заработало
